# Server Socket: No port Forwarding

Tags: java, sockets, port, forwarding

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Anyways, I made an android application, (This isn't an android question), and it connects to your computer so you can monitor it. Well I have the server for the computer ready to the client from the phone can access it, it works perfectly. The problem is, You have to port forward, and not everybody knows how to do that. Is there a way so you can programmatically make it so you do not have to port forward?
Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds like this is a question of how to configure your network.  Your software cannot get around your network configuration otherwise there would be no point having a firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you had to set up port forwarding on your router (because you're using a router with your broadband connection)?

No.

You would need to set up a intermediary server on the internet somewhere that both could connect to, then forward the data through that.

Answer (score 2):

You can have both connect to a server of yours. More of a pain than any other method, but guaranteed to work.

I'm not sure about the specifics of the droid, but you may be able to access the droid directly through its IP.

Otherwise you could set up a simple tutorial program, with specific instructions on how to port forward. You could even make a little program to access certain popular vendors port forwarding directly. Maybe just a little thing that asks for a password and connects and does everything automatically. Wouldn't be horribly difficult with some vendors.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys, I might do both connect to a server, don't know yet. The tutorial program could work ok too, Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. If at all possible I'd go for the server- the less an end user has to do, the better.